# Slidetoggle on generated lists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

*A small disclaimer - I am very very very fresh at jQuery*

I am currently working on a website that has a custom post type archive page, and on it I am grouping the term in lists. Each term has it's own `<ul>`. Now I am trying to only show 4 list items, and place the others under a toggle. I tried making the `'term-list'` class and the `'see-all'` class dynamic, by basing them on the $term->slug. This will work, but I will end up having to write a function for each term block, which is something I want to prevent.

My code:

```
<div class="overview-block-travel column one_third">
  <div class="overview-block-travel-inner">
    <?php $image = get_field('country_flag_image', $term); ?>
      <img class="country-flag" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

      <h3 class="overview-block-country-head">
        <?php echo $term->name ?>
      </h3>

      <ul class="term-list">
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <li class="post-listing" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php echo get_template_part('assets/svg/arrow-right-icon.svg'); ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>
        </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </ul>

      <span class="see-all">See all routes</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My rendered html:

```js
jQuery('.see-all').on('click', function() {
  jQuery('.overview-block-travel-inner')
    .find('ul.term-list li:nth-of-type(1n+5)').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overview-block-travel-inner">
  <h3 class="overview-block-country-head">The Netherlands</h3>
  <ul class="term-list">
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-910">
      <a href="/test-6/">test 6</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-908">
      <a href="/test5/">test5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-906">
      <a href="/test4/">test4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-904">
      <a href="/test3/">test3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-743">
      <a href="/test-route-2/">test route 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-737">
      <a href="/test-cycling-route/">Test cycling route</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="see-all">See all routes</span>
</div>
<div class="overview-block-travel-inner">
  <h3 class="overview-block-country-head">The Mountians</h3>
  <ul class="term-list">
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-710">
      <a href="/test-6/">test 6</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-778">
      <a href="/test5/">test5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-706">
      <a href="/test4/">test4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-704">
      <a href="/test3/">test3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-643">
      <a href="/test-route-2/">test route 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-637">
      <a href="/test-cycling-route/">Test cycling route</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="see-all">See all routes 2</span>
</div>
```

I tried a few different methods, but I can't seem to get it to work. My latest attempt was using `jQuery.each()`, but I may have been using that in the wrong way. I also thought maybe the `.find` option would solve it, but I think it's just finding the closest one to each `.overview-block-travel`, so no luck there.

Comment: Since your question really appears to be focused on jQuery, perhaps put the rendered HTML in instead of the php.

Comment: I added my rendered html, thank you :)

Comment: Note I Added second group to show the failure condition (toggles both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to make it all relative to the element inside which the 'see all' button was clicked:

```
jQuery('.see-all').on('click', function() {
  // `this` will be the 'see all' element that was clicked
  jQuery(this).parent()
    .find('ul.term-list li:nth-of-type(1n+5)').slideToggle();
});
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cp6w91qw/)

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the solution. Thank you for teaching me something new :)

Comment: You're welcome. As Mark Schultheiss points out, there are some nice alternative traversal methods jQuery provides such as `.closest()` should you ever be working with unpredictable markup.

Answer (score 0):

It just might be as simple as adding a click handler trigger to initially hide them?  Note my assumption here is multiple groups of the `'overview-block-travel-inner'` class hence the `.closest()` with that class in there.

Note: why this way?  IF you use `.closest('.overview-block-travel-inner')` then if you decide for example to alter your markup on the "See all routes" to for example make it different by a wrap of it then it still works i.e. as we might see:

`<label class="btn btn-primary active"><span class="see-all">See all routes</a></label>`

So then the `.parent()` would fail.

```js
jQuery('.see-all').on('click', function() {
  jQuery(this).closest('.overview-block-travel-inner')
    .find('ul.term-list li:nth-of-type(1n+5)').slideToggle();
}).trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overview-block-travel-inner">
  <h3 class="overview-block-country-head">The Netherlands</h3>
  <ul class="term-list">
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-910">
      <a href="/test-6/">test 6</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-908">
      <a href="/test5/">test5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-906">
      <a href="/test4/">test4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-904">
      <a href="/test3/">test3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-743">
      <a href="/test-route-2/">test route 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-737">
      <a href="/test-cycling-route/">Test cycling route</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="see-all">See all routes</span>
</div>
<div class="overview-block-travel-inner">
  <h3 class="overview-block-country-head">The Mountians</h3>
  <ul class="term-list">
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-710">
      <a href="/test-6/">test 6</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-778">
      <a href="/test5/">test5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-706">
      <a href="/test4/">test4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-704">
      <a href="/test3/">test3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-643">
      <a href="/test-route-2/">test route 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="post-listing" id="post-637">
      <a href="/test-cycling-route/">Test cycling route</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <span class="see-all">See all Mountian routes 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you very much! I did try using .closest() at some point, but it didn't work at that point. I noticed from your example that I made a mistake with the target of .closest when I used it. Thanks!